# How to validate e-mail format in textbox?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to put validator so that if the user does not put the email id in correct format i.e. abc@xyz.com, a error message should pop-up. How do I put this validator for Windows Mobile?

Comment: Windows mobile (per question) or Windows phone (per tag)? Those are two very different mobile platforms, after all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  public static bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
       {
           // Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format.
           return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, 
                  @"^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))" + 
                  @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$"); 
       }
```